# highcharts - to show a no data picture in case nothing to render from mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

i have been looking here and on the internet for a solution about showing a no data pic on the highcharts' DIV when the query doesn't return any thing from the database.

mysql query

```
$GetData= "SELECT COUNT( * ) AS  `items count` ,  `items` 
FROM  `items` 
where repdate = curdate()
GROUP BY  `items` 
ORDER BY  `items count` DESC  ";
```

my table code

```
<table width="313" id="datatable" style="display:none;">
 <thead>
 <tr>
            <th>column 1</th>
            <th>column 2</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    <?php

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($GetData)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>" . $row['items'] . "</th>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['items count'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
  ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

example:

where the mysql query doesn't return any data, i get the following.

[image]

how to stop highcharts from rendering if there is no data returned ? and replace it with a picture

similar example [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V248t/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your options variable to see if there is any data, and render the chart only if data exists.

```
if (options.series.length > 0) {
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
}
```

Comment: my query while no data is back like' <table width="313" id="datatable" style="display:none;">
 <thead>
 <tr>  
   <th>items</th>
   <th>items count</th>
  </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
 </tbody>
</table>
'which doesn't work with the above because the series count start with the first row , and i cant loop the table head inside while .. any other solution

Comment: Then add a counter for the actual data, and check it before you render the graph :)